# New tag suggestion: “Elektronika BK” @ “Retrocomputing”

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

Writing here as [recommended by the moderator there](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/15407) for the flag I raised to [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13096)

Shouldn't we create a tag on "Electronika BK" ? Synonym tags, "BK0010", "BK-0010" and "BK 0010". This machine seems to pop up often on retrocomputing...

The posts I found mentioning that machine are

- [Were there any LSI-11 like home computers outside of Russia?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5204)
- [What causes the monitor to reduce to four lines on BK 0010 Focal?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13096) (mentions `BK 0010` term)
- [Was Vilnius BASIC cross-platform?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/10965) (mentions `BK-0010` term)

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't we create a tag on "Electronika BK"

Makes sense. Thus added as [electronika-bk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronika-bk) to cover all models (0010/11).

> This machine seems to pop up often on retrocomputing

With just three questions so far the term 'often' is maybe a bit ahead of time.
As of now, it doesn't make much sense to restrict it to the BK-0010 series or put in synonyms.

Comment: Cheers. Hm, indeed only 3 questions so far, but I came across 2 of them at random (probably the world is too small after all). I personally may contribute to the public knowledge about `Electronika-BK`, once I sort out other problems in my life

Comment: @tabdiukov Yes, it's a small world. And the net is like the town square :) You're quite welcome to add you knowledge in answers - not just for the BK series. In fact, I may have a few - if I ever manage to get my Ш setup completed - I'm missing everything but the console :( (P.S.: mind to populate your profile?)